# editing a list in a different file

Tags: python, list

I am trying to edit a list in a different file in python. I have a file called models.py and a file called details.py,

details.py:

```
DATA = [
{'height': '184', 'width': '49'},
{'height': '161', 'width': '31'},
{'height': '197', 'width': '25'},
{'height': '123', 'width': '56'},
{'height': '152', 'width': '24'},
{'height': '177', 'width': '27'},
 ]

def edit_list(h,w):
    for info in DATA:
        if info['height'] == h:
           info['width'] = w
    return True
```

```
models.py:

from abc.details import edit_list

height = '161'
new_width = '52' 
update_data = edit_list(height, new_width) #this doesn't work, when I check the file nothing changes in the list :/
```

What is the best approach to make this possible??

(I don't want to import this list to DB and just update the width there, I want the width to update inside the file itself, removing details.py file and creating a new one using python whenever an edit takes place is not possible because few other functions are taking data from the list as well all the time.

Comment: What do you mean "when I check the file nothing changes"?  This code is certainly not going to update the actual .py file.  Show us the actual code you are using to "check the file".

Comment: `update_data = edit_list(...)` The function always returns True.  So there isn't much use in saving the return value.

Comment: "This code is certainly not going to update the actual .py file." this is exactly what I need to be done, how can I do that??

Comment: If you need to store values in a file, and update them from time to time, then storing them in a json file would be a much better choice than storing them directly in a python script.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, So what would you suggest? reading the Json file using a python script then updating values and overwriting the file? This sounds like a good plan as to keep things that will be updated in a Json file and static things in a python file!

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your statement info['width'] = w, otherwise you will not get the result you expect. More importantly, you need to 'un-indent' your return statement. At the moment, you return from the function after executing the first row in your for statement. The rest of the rows never get executed.

```
def edit_list(h,w):
    for info in DATA:
        if info['height'] == h:
            info['width'] = w
    return True
```

To use DATA as a global variable and thus be able to change its value in such a way that changed value persists, you need to change details.py to:

```
DATA = [
{'height': '184', 'width': '49'},
{'height': '161', 'width': '31'},
{'height': '197', 'width': '25'},
{'height': '123', 'width': '56'},
{'height': '152', 'width': '24'},
{'height': '177', 'width': '27'},
 ]


def edit_list(h,w):
    global DATA

    for info in DATA:
        if info['height'] == h:
            info['width'] = w
    return True
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't display correctly of course I have it indent correctly otherwise it will cause an issue anyway.. but this doesn't answer my question which is: The data is not updating...

Comment: In that case I don't know. It works for me. The only change I made was your import Statement 'from abc.details import edit_list' I have as 'from details import edit_list, DATA'. I only added DATA to be able to print it and it worked. The row {'height': '161', 'width': '31'} became {'height': '161', 'width': '52'}. I assume you have abc.detail because you have a different file structure. I suspect you are not getting the path to details.py correct. Try putting it in the same folder as models and using the same import as me.

Comment: I can fetch the data from the list without any issue but if I want to update that list its not working. Ooops I think it could be a permission issue?.. because its in a different folder? I can move it of course for testing now but I cant keep it structured that way as many other functions depend on it and are calling it from modelname.filename.py

Comment: I have tried it in as well python manage.py shell its not updating, I can fetch data fine but I cant write anything and save it to that list.

Comment: Are you doing the change in memory? Or have you checked the file itself that the list did really update there?

Comment: Where exactly is DATA stored that you want to see changed but do not see it changed? Are you expecting the initialization statement in details.py to reflect the changes?

Comment: The DATA list is stored in details.py file. Yes I am expecting the info in details.py to reflect the changes. So if another function tries to fetch some data from details.py it will get whatever data available there, if an update for the data took place then I expect any function calling details.py from models.py to get the correct changes. I know I can use a DB model to save and update this data but I want to do it in the file itself instead for some reasons I have in place.

Comment: You can only hard code initial values via a variable declaration. You can't then change the text in the code programmatically. To achieve what you want you need to set up DATA as a global variable.  Your original declaration is fine as is. You can read global variables just like you would a local variable, but to write to a global variable and have that new value persist you must redeclare the  variable as global in the function using the global keyword, eg `global DATA`. See my edited answer above

Comment: It doesn't work I have tried using global DATA like you have put up. After running the python script when I go to the folder and find details.py I open it using text editor and the old value is still there no update is showing..

Comment: You CANNOT change the code in a .py file while using that file in a project. If you want to make a change to a dataset so permanent that it lasts AFTER your code has finished running (and so the new value is available next time you run the code) you must store to an external file (a .csv, .txt, .ini for example) and initiate the variable by reading the external file into it every time you run the code. If you just want the changes to persist only while you code run (and thus be reset to the original value each time you rerun the code), then the global declaration will work.